# How to check for duplicate items in todolist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to restrict the addition of identical tasks and show an alert "there is already such a task") when someone tries it.

```
$('#list-items').html(localStorage.getItem('listItems'));
$('.add-items').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var item = $('#todo-list-item').val();

    if (item) {
        $('#list-items').append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");
        localStorage.setItem('listItems', $('#list-items').html());
        $('#todo-list-item').val("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) the `li` elements and check if any of the elements have the same [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) as the input value.

Before comparing, we need to remove the `x` added by the `remove` anchor using [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), then [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the text, and make it lower case using [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Click on "Run code snippet" to test it out:

```js
$('#add-items').click(function(event) {
    var item = $('#todo-list-item').val().trim();
    let itemCount = $("#list-items li").filter((i, li) => {
        let text = $(li).text().trim().toLowerCase();
        return text.substring(0, text.length-1) === item.toLowerCase();
    }).length;

    if (itemCount > 0) {
        alert("There is already such a task");
        return;
    }

    if (item && itemCount === 0) {
        $('#list-items').append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");
        $('#todo-list-item').val("");
    }
});
```

```css
.remove {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="todo-list-item" />
<button id="add-items">Add</button>

<ul id="list-items">
</ul>
```